# Css format not recognized after running javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, css

`Guys thank you in advance, this is my issue:

I'm building a survey that ask the user one question and 5 answers and depending on the answer it displays another question.  All this questions are contained in a table that shows the format based in a css file. The optional questions are hidden by default using `style="display:none"` and I have a java script function that shows this hidden question when one of the options is selected. This hidden question has the same class than the others "css", but for some reason when this optional question is displayed the format is not the same than the others, it's seems to me that the css is not been recognized.

JavaScript Function:

```
<script>
function showTag(X_Value)
{
    document.getElementById(X_Value).style.display = "block"; 
}

function hideTag()
{
    document.getElementById("Hide-Show").style.display = "none";  
}
</script>
```

This image shows how looks the optional question, as you can see is not formated as the others

[image]

html code regarding the first and the optional question:

HTML Code

```
    <form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">

    <table  id="customerquestions" cellspacing="20" cellpadding="0"  width="100"  >
    <tbody >



    <tr class="rowa">
    <td class="col1 cell" style="text-align: left;"> <input TYPE="radio" Name="Q1"    Value="1"checked="" >How would you rate the company in motivating you? </td>
    <td class="col2 cell"><input TYPE="radio" Name="A1" Value="Excellent"onclick="hideTag('Hide-Show')"> </td>
    <td class="col3 cell"><input TYPE="radio" Name="A1" Value="Good" onclick="hideTag('Hide-Show')"> </td>
    <td class="col4 cell"><input TYPE="radio" Name="A1" Value="Acceptable"onclick="hideTag('Hide-Show')"> </td>  
    <td class="col5 cell"><input TYPE="radio" Name="A1" Value="Poor"onclick="hideTag('Hide-Show')"> </td> 
    <td class="col6 cell"><input TYPE="radio" Name="A1"  Value="Very poor"onclick="showTag('Hide-Show')"> </td>  
</tr>


<tr class="rowa" id="Hide-Show" style="display:none" >
    <td class="col1 cell" style="text-align: left;"> <input TYPE="radio" Name="Q2" Value="2"checked="" >What is affecting your motivation </td> 
    <td class="col2 cell"><input TYPE="radio" Name="A1" Value="Option 1">Option 1</td>
    <td class="col3 cell"><input TYPE="radio" Name="A1" Value="Option 2"> Option 1</td>
    <td class="col4 cell"><input TYPE="radio" Name="A1" Value="Option 3">Option 1 </td>  
    <td class="col4 cell"><input TYPE="radio" Name="A1" Value="Option 4">Option 1 </td>  
    <td class="col5 cell"><input TYPE="radio" Name="A1" Value="Option 5"> Option 1 </td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML code?  Perhaps the option group is nested inside of the left div.

Comment: Please don't be lazy and post an impossible-to-read screenshot of your code. Copy-and-paste it into the question, and ensure it is formatted properly.

Comment: Try setting the display to `''` instead of `'block'`.

Comment: Sorry ! i thought the picture was the best option  i didn't realize the code looks good until now that i posted.

Comment: I think you meant `action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"` in your `form` tag. Regardless of what variable you want to output, right now you are not echoing anything in the action value, use either `<?php echo` or `<?=`, the short-hand for echoing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table row is different type of element than a block element (such as a `div`). Change

`document.getElementById(X_Value).style.display = "block";`

to

`document.getElementById(X_Value).style.display = "table-row";`

Generally speaking, when you are unhiding an element, you want to return its display value to its natural state. For example, for `<p>` and `<div>`, the natural value of *display* is `block`; for `<span>` it is `inline`; for `<tr>` elements it is the more specific value `table-row`.

When you want to set an elements *display* value to its default, you can do this without knowing the default value by setting the value to an empty string. E.g.

`document.getElementById(X_Value).style.display = ''; // set display to default`

Comment: You are the man !! thank you it works perfect.  Can you please explain  in more detail why wasn't working?

Comment: I tripped up on the same thing a long time ago, and from what I can tell some elements are simply unable to behave like block-style elements. In the case of elements that are sub-elements of a table, they must adhere to the confines of that context.